# responsive website design with css absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

How would I make this css into a responsive website?
I figured I have to use.

```
   @media (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 1150px) {

    #div{position:absolute;left:149px;top:61px;}

    #div2{position:absolute;left:249px;top:81px;}
   #div2{position:absolute;left:249px;top:81px;}
   #div3{position:absolute;left:279px;top:181px;}
   #div4{position:absolute;left:449px;top:121px;}
    }
```

But there are a lot of `div`s any fast way to do this?
Editing like 45 of these `div`s will take forever.
Im really new to this, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't be absolutely positioning that many DIVs anyway. CSS is designed to allow you to float/position elements naturally and then using media queries, adjust their size/float/position or hide them entirely.

Answer (score 13):

To make it responsive, you must not use `px`-values. Always use `%`-values instead.

You can use tools like this one http://rqrwd.com/ to calculate px into %-values.

Nevertheless, I don't understand why you need so much absolute-positioning. In responsive-desgin, the container should 'float' - Absolute positioning (even with %-values) makes that impossible.

```
but there are alot of divs any fast way to do this?
```

You don't have to write the design for each div. Furthermore, I think your syntax `#div` is not ideal - div2 and div3 have the exact same layout - use a class instead!

**To apply css-styles to all divs:**

```
div {
   width: 40%
}
```

**To apply a syntax to only one container:**

HTML: `<div id='unique'>content</div>`

```
#unique {
   width: 40%
}
```

**To apply a syntax to several containers (but not all):**

HTML: `<div class='flat'>content</div><div class='flat'>content</div>`

```
.flat {
   width: 40%
}
```

or

```
#div2, #div3, .flat {
   width: 40%
}
```

You should probably take a look at this short css-introduction: http://www.cssbasics.com/introduction-to-css/

Comment: If you designed your css correct, and always used %-values, you avoid defining dozens of media-queries. In good designs they are neccessary, yes, but a basic layout, which looks good on nearly every device is also possible without them.

Comment: +1 for "I don't understand why you need so much absolute-positioning in responsive design." [Responsive design](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design) begins with flexible grids, flexible images and media queries.

Comment: Good answer.
Side thought: http://rqrwd.com/ So there is an entirely dedicated website for a simple percentage calculation? :)